# Formatar String

Tags: java, string

Tenho o seguinte código de exemplo:

```
String _randomTag = "pvp";
String _randomTag2 = "otherName";
String _format = "{tag} {player} {" + _randomTag + "} {" + _randomTag + "} > {msg}"
String _result = _format.replace("{tag}", "MODERADOR").replace("{player}", "João").replace("{msg}", "uma mensagem.")
```

O resultado será:

> "MODERADOR João {pvp} {otherName} > uma mensagem."

Quero remover as outras 'tags' (`{pvp}` e `{otherName}`), ficando um resultado assim: "`MODERADOR João > uma mensagem.`", lembrando que as variáveis `_randomTag` e `_randomTag2` terão nomes aleatórios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String templateTexto = "{tag} {player} {abacaxi} {banana} > {msg}";
        Map<String, String> substituicoes = new HashMap<>();
        substituicoes.put("tag", "MODERADOR");
        substituicoes.put("player", "João");
        substituicoes.put("msg", "uma mensagem.");

        Template template = new Template(templateTexto);
        String substituido = template.substituir(substituicoes);
        System.out.println(substituido);
    }
}

class Template {

    private final String template;
    private final Set<String> tags;

    public Template(String template) {
        this.template = template;
        this.tags = new TreeSet<>();
        StringBuilder nomeVariavel = null;
        boolean variavel = false;
        for (char c : template.toCharArray()) {
            if (!variavel && c == '{') {
                variavel = true;
                nomeVariavel = new StringBuilder();
            } else if (variavel && c == '}') {
                variavel = false;
                tags.add(nomeVariavel.toString());
                nomeVariavel = null;
            } else if (variavel) {
                nomeVariavel.append(c);
            }
        }
    }

    public String substituir(Map<String, String> substituicoes) {
        String texto = template;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : substituicoes.entrySet()) {
            texto = texto.replace("{" + entry.getKey() + "}", entry.getValue());
        }
        for (String tag : tags) {
            if (substituicoes.containsKey(tag)) continue;
            texto = texto.replace("{" + tag + "} ", "");
            texto = texto.replace("{" + tag + "}", "");
        }
        return texto;
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
MODERADOR João > uma mensagem.
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/XDzsz4)

Neste código, a classe `Template` representa o texto com as tags. Ela tem um método para fazer a substituição, de acordo com um `Map`. Note que a implementação da classe `Template` é um pequeno compilador (o construtor dela é baseada em um autômato de dois estados).

No `main`, é efetuado o teste dele. Lá, é construída uma instância do `Template`, é construído o `Map` com as substituições desejadas, são realizadas as substituições e exibe-se o resultado.

O método `substituir` apenas começa com o texto do template e sai fazendo as substituições das tags pelos substitutos especificados no `Map`. Depois disso, os elementos que não forem encontrados no `Map`, que correspondem as demais tags, são eliminados. Note o detalhe que ele também se preocupa em retirar o espaço que possa haver no template depois de uma tag que será eliminada.

Comment: Este código era exatamente o que eu precisava, obrigado!

Comment: @Krash0 vejo que você aceitou a outra resposta, mesmo dizendo que esta é que atendeu, houve algum equivoco?

Answer (score 5):

Se for algo simples, pode usar o método [`format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-):

```
String moderator = "João";
int messages = 3;

// João tem 3 mensagens.
String.format("%s tem %s mensagens.", moderator, messages);
```

Se for algo um pouco mais complicado, pode usar [`MessageFormat.format(pattern, arguments)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).
O primeiro argumento a ser enviado é uma string de modelo contendo entre chaves o que deverá ser substituído pelos valores do parâmetro `arguments`. Por exemplo:

```
// Olá! Eu me chamo Krash0
MessageFormat.format("Olá! Eu me chamo {0}.", "Krash0"); 

// Tom Hanks não é meu nome, me chamo Krash0
MessageFormat.format("{1} não é meu nome, me chamo {0}", "Tom Hanks", "Krash0");
```

Aplicando no seu caso, ficaria:

```
String playerName = "João";
String playerType = "MODERADOR";
String gameType   = "pvp";
int messages = 10;

String output = MessageFormat.format("[{0}] {1} [{2}] > {3} mensagens.",
                playerType, playerName, gameType, messages);

// [MODERADOR] João [pvp] > 10 mensagens.
```

#### [Funcionando no IDEONE](http://ideone.com/peP2nd)

Comment: +1 Legal esse uso do format :)

Comment: Acho que a ideia era eliminar o `[pvp]` da saída.

Answer (score -1):

No caso do código acima {pvp} {otherName} não estão sendo mencionadas nos replaces.
Podemos simplificar esse código.

```
String user = "João";

 String mensagem = "MODERADOR" + user + "> uma mensagem";
```

Comment: Pelo que deu a entender da pergunta, esta solução não é a que o OP deseja. Ele parece querer trabalhar com "tags"

Comment: Não é possível, os replace's na variável _result é justamente para substituir as "tags" pelo seu devido nome.